# Landing Page Based on Role?

Tags: users

Use Case - I've got several Dashboards (some custom View pages) in the site. Depending on the Role associated with a User, I want to direct them to thier respective Dashboard.

So an Editor would go to the Editor Dashboard, a Contributor would go to a Contributor Dashboard, etc. after they login.

(I'm using the OpenPublic distro)

Comment: Do you want to redirect user just after login???

Comment: You can do this with the rules modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect user after checking their role(by using below PHP snippet)

```
<?php $GLOBALS['user']->roles; ?>
```

Your code will look something like this:

```
<?php 
if($GLOBALS['user']->roles == 'editor') {
  drupal_goto("dashboard_editor"));
}
?>
```

Note: this will work only when a user has single role associated with him.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a panels for the dashboard and then create different variants based on roles using the Access rules.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the login destination module. Simple as that.

https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination

Answer (score 0):

Few methods you could do this:

1) `hook_init()` - check user's role and redirect to the correct address.

2) With the Pages module, you can set each panel's (=view's) display rule as having a certain role. With this you can stay at the same address (say, `/dashboard`)